# Managing overview of complex distributed network

Tags: management, documentation

I hope this question is not too stupid, I am very unexperienced with medium to large scale distributed network deployments.

Imagine you have corporate datacenters and fragmented intranets distributed over the globe, say 50+.

What is the best way to capture and track the network architecture if it comes to details and long term development? What is typically used here? In terms, not due to matter of taste, but how to assess pros and cons?

- Whiteboard: hard to share and collaborate globally
- Diagramming tool like Visio (currently my preference)
- Model the graph say like graphviz but not sure if I will get lost in technical details and rendering layout issues
- some specialized family of tools I am not aware of
- data driven high end network monitoring (?) solutions, maybe a GIS (Geo Informational System) with plugins for data interfaces - I also fail to identify how to identify such products on the market

Comment: Sorry, resource recommendations and opinions are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. But I'd stay with Visio mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you'll need multiple detail levels as you cannot hope to put everything into a single diagram.

I'd create a summary diagram with all locations from a high level of perspective. Make sure you summarizingly include services that matter to the whole. Leave out all details that have only local significance.

For each location, do a more detailed graph. Larger or more complex locations may require another split in detail level - geographically or even on a by-service level (e.g. SAN, virtual host clusters, large DNS, DHCP, LDAP structures, ...). If possible, use templates for locations with similar architecture.